# javax.validation.valid on child objects

Tags: java, spring, validation, methods

I've got a simple structure

```
public class Parent {
    @Size(min = 5, max = 10)
    String lastName;
    List<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {
    @Size(min = 5, max = 10)
    String firstName;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 18)
    Integer age;
}
```

and a method with definition

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")
public RestResponse create(@RequestBody Parent object)
```

which creates (and gives a possibility to update) parent objects.

Let's assume that I'd like to create two functionalities:

1) To create a working copy - user doesn't have to insert correctly all of the data.

2) To send me this data - in this example I'd like to valid if they're correct.

I've found that there is a way to valid it by adding @Valid annotation to the parameter in method definition, like that:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")
public RestResponse create(@RequestBody @Valid Parent object)
```

but it do valid only parent field, skipping childs. I can add @Valid annotation on child list:

```
public class Parent {
    @Size(min = 5, max = 10)
    String lastName;
    List<Child> childs;
}
```

but it'll work all the time - even when I'd like to save a working copy. Is it possible to valid objects inside parent object conditionally?

Answer (score 18):

Just Add @Valid to your childList and it should work

```
public class Parent {
@Size(min = 5, max = 10)
String lastName;
@Valid
List<Child> childs;
```

}

Comment: For Kotlin data classes, `@field@valid` or `@get@valid` will do.

Comment: In Kotlin, `@get:Valid` works, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [validation groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups). In that case your model might look like:

```
public class Parent {

    @Size(min = 5, max = 10, groups = { Draft.class, FinalVersion.class })
    String lastName;
    @Valid
    List<Child> childs;
}

public class Child {

    @Size(min = 5, max = 10, groups = FinalVersion.class)
    String firstName;
    @Range(min = 1, max = 18, groups = FinalVersion.class)
    Integer age;

}
```

Also note that `@Size` is not supported for Integer type - you might want to use either `@Range` or a pair of `@Min` `@Max` (which is essentially the same thing).
`Draft` and `FinalVersion` are just simple interfaces, to define validation groups:

```
interface Draft {
}

interface FinalVersion {
}
```

And then in your controllers you need to use `@Validated` on your bean parameter instead of `@Valid`, as first one allows you to choose validation group. So your controller then will look like:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "saveDraft", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public RestResponse create(@RequestBody @Validated(Draft.class) Parent object) {
    // your stiff here
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "submitFinal", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public RestResponse create(@RequestBody @Validated(FinalVersion.class) Parent object) {
    // your stiff here
}
```

But you'll need to have two methods to handle the post - one for draft and one for final submit.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `@Valid` and validate it always. If you don't care about valid children you can add `BindingResult bindingResult` to the controller method to prevent default validation and the go through the error list ignoring the invalid children.

Use `bindingResult.hasFieldErrors(fieldName)` method.

or you can create one more ParentExt extending Parent and add `@Valid` on getter rather than on the field.

Answer (score 0):

Well... that can be achieved with oval validation framework. It look's same, but give you more functions.

http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#declaring-conditional-constraints

@AssertValid(**when**="something!=null") - something like that

If not, then for some cases You should use standard Validator class.